# import data from mysql to delta lake by spark-submit

Tags: mysql, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

shell is:

```
spark-submit 
    --class "io.delta.connectors.spark.jdbc.ImportRunner" sql-delta-import.jar 
    --jdbc-url jdbc:mysql://root:password!@hadoop1:3306/db 
    --source test 
    --destination default.delta-table 
    --split-by id 
    --chunks 5
```

1.error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
Possibly unquoted identifier delta-table detected. Please consider quoting it with 
back-quotes as `delta-table`(line 1, pos 13)
== SQL ==
default.delta-table
-------------^^^
```

2. when default.delta-table change to default.`delta-table`
   error change to:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting {'ADD', 'AFTER', 'ALL', 'ALTER',
```

3. 

`--destination default.delta-table`  change to `--destination /tmp/delta-table`

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input '/' expecting {'ADD', ...
```

`/tmp/delta-table` created by `spark-shell` exists in hadoop.

i not know how to solve it